# Go JS Tree view equivalent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gojs

I need to achieve the tree view ([Go JS Tree View](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/treeView.html)). The respective tree view sample source code without React JS is at ([Tree View Source Code](https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS/blob/master/samples/treeView.html)). I'm trying to do the same using React JS and have the following code written. But somehow I'm missing something and the diagram/tree view is not rendering. Can you please help me to figure out the issue?

```
import React from 'react';
import * as go from 'gojs';
import { ReactDiagram } from 'gojs-react';
import '../../../App.css';

go.Shape.defineFigureGenerator("ExpandedLine", function(shape, w, h) {
  return new go.Geometry()
    .add(new go.PathFigure(0, 0.25*h, false)
      .add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Line, .5 * w, 0.75*h))
      .add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Line, w, 0.25*h)));
});

// use a sideways V figure instead of PlusLine in the TreeExpanderButton
go.Shape.defineFigureGenerator("CollapsedLine", function(shape, w, h) {
  return new go.Geometry()
    .add(new go.PathFigure(0.25*w, 0, false)
      .add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Line, 0.75*w, .5 * h))
      .add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Line, 0.25*w, h)));
});

let nodeDataArray = [{ key: 0 }];

const initDiagram = () => {

  let $ = go.GraphObject.make;

  const diagram =
    $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
      {
        allowMove: false,
        allowCopy: false,
        allowDelete: false,
        allowHorizontalScroll: false,
        layout:
          $(go.TreeLayout,
            {
              alignment: go.TreeLayout.AlignmentStart,
              angle: 0,
              compaction: go.TreeLayout.CompactionNone,
              layerSpacing: 16,
              layerSpacingParentOverlap: 1,
              nodeIndentPastParent: 1.0,
              nodeSpacing: 0,
              setsPortSpot: false,
              setsChildPortSpot: false
            })
      });

  diagram.nodeTemplate =
    $(go.Node,
      { // no Adornment: instead change panel background color by binding to Node.isSelected
        selectionAdorned: false,
        // a custom function to allow expanding/collapsing on double-click
        // this uses similar logic to a TreeExpanderButton
        doubleClick: function(e, node) {
          let cmd = diagram.commandHandler;
          if (node.isTreeExpanded) {
            if (!cmd.canCollapseTree(node)) return;
          } else {
            if (!cmd.canExpandTree(node)) return;
          }
          e.handled = true;
          if (node.isTreeExpanded) {
            cmd.collapseTree(node);
          } else {
            cmd.expandTree(node);
          }
        }
      },
      $("TreeExpanderButton",
        { // customize the button's appearance
          "_treeExpandedFigure": "ExpandedLine",
          "_treeCollapsedFigure": "CollapsedLine",
          "ButtonBorder.fill": "whitesmoke",
          "ButtonBorder.stroke": null,
          "_buttonFillOver": "rgba(0,128,255,0.25)",
          "_buttonStrokeOver": null
        }),
      $(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
        { position: new go.Point(18, 0) },
        new go.Binding("background", "isSelected",
            s => (s ? 'lightblue' : 'white')).ofObject(),
        $(go.Picture,
          {
            width: 18, height: 18,
            margin: new go.Margin(0, 4, 0, 0),
            imageStretch: go.GraphObject.Uniform
          },
          // bind the picture source on two properties of the Node
          // to display open folder, closed folder, or document
          new go.Binding("source", "isTreeExpanded", imageConverter).ofObject(),
          new go.Binding("source", "isTreeLeaf", imageConverter).ofObject()),
        $(go.TextBlock,
          { font: '9pt Verdana, sans-serif' },
          new go.Binding("text", "key", function(s) { return "item " + s; }))
      )  // end Horizontal Panel
    );  // end Node

  diagram.linkTemplate = $(go.Link);

  let max = 499;
  let count = 0;
  while (count < max) {
    count = makeTree(3, count, max, nodeDataArray, nodeDataArray[0]);
  }
  diagram.model = new go.TreeModel(nodeDataArray);

  return diagram;
}

function makeTree(level, count, max, nodeDataArray, parentData) {
  let numChildren = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  for (let i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
    if (count >= max) return count;
    count++;
    let childData = { key: count, parent: parentData.key };
    nodeDataArray.push(childData);
    if (level > 0 && Math.random() > 0.5) {
      count = makeTree(level - 1, count, max, nodeDataArray, childData);
    }
  }
  return count;
}

function imageConverter(prop, picture) {
  let node = picture.part;
  if (node.isTreeLeaf) {
    return "images/document.svg";
  } else {
    if (node.isTreeExpanded) {
      return "images/openFolder.svg";
    } else {
      return "images/closedFolder.svg";
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initDiagram);

const TreeView = () => {

  return (
    <>
      GO JS
      <div id="myDiagramDiv">
        <ReactDiagram
          initDiagram={initDiagram}
          divClassName='diagram-component'
          nodeDataArray={nodeDataArray}
          skipsDiagramUpdate={false}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default TreeView;
```

Comment: Also, I am not familiar with that library but since `gojs-react` seems geared toward react are you sure you need all that init code or maybe the library have some props that would do the job? While my answer could work I feel that you are bypassing gojs-react instead of using it to it's full potential

Comment: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/react.html#Installation this is how we do in react

Comment: I notice that in the exemple from the page you posted they don't call initDiagram and instead they pass it as a props. Maybe you dont need to call it manually? Do you have anything in the console?

Comment: When I remove  id "myDiagramDiv" in initDiagram(), it is working. Not sure why!!

Comment: Could be a bug in the library or something with some CSS that is applied on that div

Answer (score 1):

When React start executing, the `DOMContentLoaded` event have already been fired. Instead try to call `initDiagram` in a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook

```
const TreeView = () => {
  useEffect(initDiagram);
  return (
    <>
      GO JS
      <div id="myDiagramDiv">
        <ReactDiagram
          initDiagram={initDiagram}
          divClassName='diagram-component'
          nodeDataArray={nodeDataArray}
          skipsDiagramUpdate={false}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```